# How to find all pythagorean triples under 1000 without control flow functions(for, while, if) in R?

Tags: r, recursion, pythagorean

Without using any control flow
statements, i.e., `if`, `while`, for write an R function that lists all such triplets `{a, b, c} less than 1000 and a < b < c`.I have no idea how to go about this problem other than knowing the which function will help. Im guessing its some sort of recursion.

Comment: Yes, recursion could do it. Give it a shot and come back otherwise you will probably get little to no help.

Comment: It may be helpful to think about how your function will work in English before trying to implement it in R.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Just because I think this is pretty
xx <- (1:1000) ^2
xy <- combn(xx,2)
xz <- rbind(xy, colSums(xy))
xp <- xz[, xz[3,] %in% xx]
sqrt(xp)
```